# Swift - How to catch nil value in SQLite query?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am using SQLite for fetching data with following code.

```
func idToName(id: String) -> String {
        do {
            if (id == "") {
             return ""
            } else {
                var SqlQuery="Select kod from id where idText="
                SqlQuery.append("\""+id+"\"")
                let stmt = try db?.prepare(SqlQuery)
                let tempScalar = try stmt?.scalar() as! String
                return tempScalar
            }
        } catch {
            print("failed")
        }
        return ""
    }
```

There is a do try catch block in statement. However when tempScalar variable is nil it is not catching in catch block and getting error how can I improve or fix that code?

Comment: by not force casting but using `if let`.

Comment: why no simply say `let tempScalar = try stmt?.scalar() as? String ?? ""` and use nil coalescing operator ?

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @MartinR How can I make it safer?

Comment: Read about prepared statements and binding. – Apparently you are using SQLite.swift, which has many higher level methods for database queries, see for example [Building Complex Queries](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#building-complex-queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out **`IFNULL`** [from here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

e.g

```
Select kod from id where idText= ifnull(id,0)
```